# get the partial match string using java regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern like below

```
Sentence = "@502348@502002662[000861@10";
Pattern = "^@(\\d{6})@*(\\d{9})\\[(\\d{6})@(\\d{2})";

Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(Sentence);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) 
      str1= regexMatcher.group(1);
      str2 = regexMatcher.group(2);
      str3 = regexMatcher.group(3);
      str4 = regexMatcher.group(4);
    }
```

The above one works fine if the sentence is appropriately matches. But my requirement is , the partial result should be returned in case the pattern is not matches appropriately.

For example if Sentence = "@114142@000017000[" then i want to get the str1 and str2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use make last part optional:

```
^@(\\d{6})@*(\\d{9})(?:\\[(\\d{6})@(\\d{2}))?
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oM3hM9/1)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can try something like

```
^@(\\d{6})(?:@*(\\d{9})(?:\\[(\\d{6})(?:@(\\d{2}))?)?)?
```

This makes

```
@xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx[xxxxxx@xx
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - optional
                 ^^^^^^^^^^ - optional
                         ^^ - optional
```